# Is there a way to apply an additional Chef recipe to a machine AFTER that machine has already been provisioned?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I have am spinning up a kubernetes cluster using Chef provisioning inside a Vagrantfile. Once the cluster is created, I would like to apply an additional Chef recipe that targets the main control node. Is there a way to do this? It is vital that the main control node be provisioned first, then the rest of the nodes to join the cluster, and finally the additional configurations should be added to the main control node.

Answer (score 0):

there is the ability to update the `run_list` of the desire nodes (control plan nodes) [to add any other cookbooks](https://docs.chef.io/run_lists/#run_list-add) that you like.

another idea, is to use [`chef_sleep` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/chef_sleep/) with some other logic to test whether the cluster is ready and continue your flow.

or, bootstrap nodes serially (one after another) and not in parallel (all together and wait for them to join the cluster).